# How can I use the Paypal Adaptive Payments SDK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

Am new to rails and I want to experiment with building a buyer and seller marketplace I want to use the paypal [ruby adaptive payment sdk](https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby#samples-app) gem for this experiment.The github page gives and example code to use for setting it up.

```
require 'paypal-sdk-adaptivepayments'
PayPal::SDK.configure(
  :mode      => "sandbox",  # Set "live" for production
  :app_id    => "APP-80W284485P519543T",
  :username  => "jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com",
  :password  => "WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F",
  :signature => "AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy" )

@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptivePayments.new

# Build request object
@pay = @api.build_pay({
  :actionType => "PAY",
  :cancelUrl => "http://localhost:3000/samples/adaptive_payments/pay",
  :currencyCode => "USD",
  :feesPayer => "SENDER",
  :ipnNotificationUrl => "http://localhost:3000/samples/adaptive_payments/ipn_notify",
  :receiverList => {
    :receiver => [{
      :amount => 1.0,
      :email => "platfo_1255612361_per@gmail.com" }] },
  :returnUrl => "http://localhost:3000/samples/adaptive_payments/pay" })

# Make API call & get response
@response = @api.pay(@pay)

# Access response
if @response.success?
  @response.payKey
  @api.payment_url(@response)  # Url to complete payment
else
  @response.error[0].message
end
```

Where would I put my customized version of this code in would it be in my OrdersController, applicationController or the UserController? I Just need a bit of guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

You either place this code inside your orders controller or inside your order model wrapped within a class or an instance method passing the necessary parameters to it which will keep your controller not much loaded with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of keeping your code more readable, you could place the above code in a class in a rails helper or lib folder and invoke the methods from there.

Though it's a pretty late answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?